# Find position of prime number based on user input

Tags: c++

This c++ code prints out the following prime numbers: `3 5 7.`

```
int main () 
{
for (int a=2; a<10; a++)
    for (int b=2; b<a; b++)
    {
        if (a % b == 0)
            break;
        else if (a == b+1)
            std::cout << a << " ";

    }
return 0;
}
```

My problem is how would like program it to show the position of the prime number ?

Example :

```
Enter a number : 2    
The 2th prime number is : 5

Enter a number : 3    
The 3th prime number is : 7
```

Comment: I think you find your answer. So you can accept my answer & up vote me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can do store prime number in an `array` Like:

```
int main () 
{
int array[10];
int counter = 0;
for (int a=2; a<10; a++)
    for (int b=2; b<a; b++)
    {
        if (a % b == 0)
            break;
        else if (a == b+1)
        {
          array[counter] = a;
          counter ++;
        }
    }
for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
cout<<"Enter a number : ";
int position;
cin>> position;
cout<< "The "<<position<<"th prime number is "<< array[position-1]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number : 2    
The 2th prime number is : 5

Enter a number : 3    
The 3th prime number is : 7
```